What should be the major product when sulfanilic acid undergoes bromination
I am having trouble in predicting the major product when sulfanilic acid undergoes bromination in the presence of bromine and a Lewis acid (Not bromine water). I am also unable to find any relevant information regarding the same.
My thoughts:
Since sulfanilic acid exists as a zwitterion, this fact should also be kept in mind.

I believe that ortho postion with respect to the SO3H must be attacked as it gives the most stable arenium as the carbocation is formed next to the sulphur which combined with the negative charge on the oxygen atom has little -I effect.

You don't really need a basic solution to activate the amino nitrogen in sulfanilic acid. According to Wikipedia, the $\pu{pK_a}$ of this acid in water is only 3.23, so even a weakly acidic aqueous solution will allow an appreciable amount of the $\ce{H2N – C6H4 – SO3^-}$ anion to exist. Then the amino group will activate and direct ortho (the para position is of course occupied by the sulfonate group), giving 4-amino-3-bromobenzenesulfonic acid or with excess bromine, 4-amino-3,5-dibromobenzenesulfonic acid. The low
$\pu{pK_a}$ of sulfanilic acid is typical of protonated amines when the nitrogen is attached to an aromatic ring.

According to this paper the product of bromination of sulfanilic acid by NBS in aq NaOH is 4-amino-3-bromobenzene sulfonic acid. This is the only literature I can locate on the bromination of sulfanilic acid. In the situation with the amino group being deactivated by protonation I would speculate that the molecule is insufficiently activated to react with bromine/Lewis acid.

But in basic solution it's a salt of the acid - deprotonated amino group. In OP's scenario it could be otherwise.

NaOH would take away the H+ from NH3+ and hence NH2 (ortho directing) will govern the reaction producing the product given in the paper. The absence of a base in my question is what's different.

TL;DR

The zwitterionic form of the molecule is likely highly electron deficient, considering it has two electron withdrawing groups on it, which already reduces its reactivity significantly.
The zwitterion also cannot stabilize the positive charge on the transition state should an electrophilic attack occur, for the same reason.
Consequently, the zwitterion should be highly unreactive (as is the case for many zwitterions) to EAS. In a solvent that is aprotic, the degree of conversion to the zwitterion will be almost none as the acid dissociation is quite low. The use of a Lewis acidic catalyst in OP's question implies a wealth of electrophiles in solution too.
As a result, the neutral sulfanilinic acid should react in similar ways to aniline, favoring ortho substitution (as the para position is occupied).


This is quite an interesting question. I suspected that the zwitterionic form, having two electron-withdrawing groups attached to it, would be really bad at undergoing any kind of EAS. This was somewhat backed up by the lack of any literature concerning the electrophilic halogenation of this molecule, instead opting for alternative routes to produce halogenated derivatives. To get a better idea of how EAS works in zwitterionic systems, I looked at another one: anthranilic acid.
Neutron diffraction studies show that the crystal structure of anthranilic acid shows it crystalizes in a monoclinic form with two distinct molecules in the unit cell: one neutral and one zwitterionic (1). If the zwitterionic form of the acid was therefore involved in the reaction, it is reasonable to assume that per mole of anthranilic acid, half would produce EAS products of the neutral form, and the other half would produce EAS products of the zwitterionic form.
Treatment of this molecule with $\ce{SO2Cl2}$ in cold ether has been reported to afford a 5-chloroanthranilic acid in a yield of roughly 50% (2). Similarly, treatment with gaseous chlorine, concentrated $\ce{HCl}$ in water afforded 3,5-dichloroanthranilic acid, in a yield of 69% (3). In glacial acetic acid, 3,5-dichloroanthranilic acid was obtained in a yield of 41-50% (4). The reaction rate was quite slow, as reported by the papers. You will notice that these are all products expected by the chlorination of the neutral molecule—shown in the figure below (I have neglected to draw all the resonance structures, but the main idea is emphasized). These papers also reported some unreacted anthranilic acid in the crude tar left in the reaction vessel. We can conclude that the zwitterionic form is inactive during chlorination.

This makes sense, considering the zwitterionic form of anthranilic acid contains a strongly electron-withdrawing $\ce{NH_3}^+$ group, alongside a carboxylate group, also electron-withdrawing. It makes sense then, that not only can the zwitterion not stabilize the positive charge developed on the arenium intermediate (try drawing the resonance structures yourself, the positive charge will always end up next to an electron-withdrawing group), but is also electron deficient, and cannot perform an attack on the electrophile, considering especially there is no catalyst to generate them in all reactions described above.
Diffraction studies of sulfanilic acid crystallized from evaporation of an aqueous solution show that it too crystallizes as a zwitterion, however the unit cell contains two molecules, both of which are in the zwitterionic forms. So, in aqueous solution, it is likely to not react at all.
In an aprotic solvent however (or indeed in a weak acid solution, eg. glacial acetic acid), the dissociation of the acid is quite low and so the zwitterionic forms should be quite low too. Such is the case for anthranilic acid too. Waylander's answer already describes the reactivity in a basic solution. Since you are using a Lewis acid to generate the electrophiles, this means a lot of electrophilic species would be in solution—therefore, I suspect you should really get ortho-subtitutions on this, just as you would with aniline.


Brown, C. J., & Ehrenberg, M. (1985). Acta Crystallographica Section C Crystal Structure Communications, 41(3), pp. 441–443.
Org. Synth. 1951, 31, 96
Atkinson, E. R., & Mitton, P. B. (1947). Journal of the American Chemical Society, 69(12), 3142–3142.
Eller, W., & Klemm, L. (1922). Berichte Der Deutschen Chemischen Gesellschaft (A and B Series), 55(1), 217–224.

